# Relative Import in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, python-import

I am having the following directory structure and I'm new to python. In folder bin I have a single file "script.py" in which I want to import "module.py" from code package. I  have seen many solutions on stackoverflow to this problem that involve modifying sys-path or giving full pathname. Is there any way I could import these with an import statement that works relatively, instead of specifying full path?

```
 project/

         bin/
             script.py

         code/
             module.py
             __init__.py
```

Answer (score 4):

To make sure that `bin/script.py` can be run without configuring environment, add this preambule to `script.py` before `from code import module` line (
from [`twisted/bin/_preambule.py`](https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/trunk/bin/_preamble.py)):

```
# insert `code/__init__.py` parent directory into `sys.path`
import sys, os

path = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]) # path to bin/script.py
while os.path.dirname(path) != path: # until top-most directory
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(path, 'code', '__init__.py')):
        sys.path.insert(0, path)
        break
    path = os.path.dirname(path)
```

The `while` loop is to support running it from `bin/some-other-directory/.../script.py`

Comment: is there any other way possible than modifying sys.path?

Comment: @bullseye: yes, there are other ways e.g., create `setup.py` for `project` and install it before running any scripts. The installation process puts `code` into a directory that is already in `sys.path` i.e., `sys.path` is not modified in this case. Also you can import any code from any source using `imp` (or `importlib` in Python 3), but you should not use it in ordinary circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

While correct, I think that the "dynamically add my current directory to the path" is a dirty, dirty hack.

Add a (possibly blank) `__init__.py` to `project`. Then add a `.pth` file containing the path to `project` to your `sites-packages` directory. Then:

`from project.code import module`

This has two advantages, in my opinion:

1) If you refactor, you just need to change the `from project.code` line and avoid messing with anything else.

2) There will be nothing special about your code -- it will behave exactly like any other package that you've installed through PyPi.

It may seem messy to add your project directory to your PYTHONPATH but I think it's a much, much cleaner solution than any of the alternatives. Personally, I've added the parent directory that all of my python code lives in to my PYTHONPATH with a `.pth` file, so I can deal with all of the code I write just like 3rd party libraries.

I don't think that there is any issue with cluttering up your PYTHONPATH, since only folders with an `__init__.py` will be importable.

Comment: will the import be absolute then, i mean project.code.module? It won't be relative right, but still a cleaner solution, i added a PYTHONPATH variable in my environment variables.

Comment: 1. My code doesn't add the current directory to the path. It searches for the parent directory that contains `code` Python package assuming common ancestry that is implied by the question ("relative import")  2. And it would be pointless to add the current directory because it is _already_ in `sys.path` when `script.py` is run as a script.

Comment: Modifying `sys.path` is a dirty hack for sure. 1. `.pth` files might be even worse unless it is created by `setup.py` upon installation of the package. If you are creating files; why wouldn't you create a simple `setup.py` file and install the module properly? And why do you need `project` directory to be a Python package? It is enough if `code` package is accessible (I assume it is not a real name otherwise it is shadowing the stdlib module with the same name) in this case `code` package behaves as any other package. 2. PYTHONPATH is even more global than a `.pth` file (more potential damage)